# OAuth2: Authorization Code Grant Flow with C#

Tags: c#, rest, redirect, oauth, authorization

I have an API that I want to consume with C# that uses OAuth2 with Authorization Code Grant Flow.

Does someone know an example or something on how to do it?

I want to know how I can return the Authorization code to my C# project after the user has logged in and given consent?

If you don't understand my question, I want to know how to go from step 1 to step 2 in this tutorial: https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/authorization-code-grant

It doesn't say how to "fetch" the "code" from the URL to my C# project.

Comment: _"C# processor"_ O_o?

Comment: Have you gotten this to work yet?

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late, but I had the same problem.
There are two solutions for getting back the code from authorization server in desktop apps.

**Inner browser**. If You want to use inner browser, like embeded [CEFSharp](https://cefsharp.github.io/), then You just want to listen to navigation event on the webbrowser control. When You authorize Your account then the server makes redirection to the specific URL that You provide. So You just catch that redirection, read the **code** from URL and cancel the redirection, hide the windows and so on.

**Outer browser**. In this case You just follow the previous steps, but insted running authorization in embeded window, You call the system browser and, what's important You set the `redirect_uri` to `localhost/whatever:{port}`. You have also run the local http server on that port (see [ephemeral port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port#:%7E:text=An%20ephemeral%20port%20is%20a%20communications%20endpoint%20%28port%29,time%20for%20the%20duration%20of%20a%20communication%20session.)), for example [`HttpListener` Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener?view=net-6.0) and when the authorization process completes, server will redirect the external browser to the localhost adress You provide. The You just catch that request on Your `HttpListener` and You've got the **code**.